# Как сделать скроллинг графика в LineChart JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Имеется около 8000 записей, по ним строится график c помощью компонента LineChart. Проблема в том, что данные на графике получаются сильно сжатыми. Как сделать скроллинг в окне?

Comment: Обратите внимание на данный пример https://gist.github.com/james-d/7252698

Comment: И этот https://gist.github.com/luizrobertofreitas/6336657

Comment: Т.е. надо писать кучу кода. Я думал проще как-то можно это сделать, одной или в несколько строк.

Comment: Решил добавлять данные на график порциями, автоматического скроллинга не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void lineChartOnScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
    NumberAxis axis;
    // scroll amount
    double translateX = (event.getDeltaX())/40;
    double translateY = event.getDeltaY()/40;


    double mousX = lineChart.getXAxis().getValueForDisplay(event.getX() - lineChart.getXAxis().getLayoutX()).doubleValue();
    double mousY = lineChart.getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(event.getY() - lineChart.getYAxis().getLayoutY()).doubleValue();

if (zoomX.isSelected()) {
   axis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getXAxis();
   axis.setAutoRanging(false);
   double delta  = (mousX - axis.getLowerBound());
   double delta1 = (axis.getUpperBound() - mousX);
   double zoomFactor = 2;

   if (translateY > 0) {
      delta = delta / zoomFactor;
      delta1 = delta1 / zoomFactor;
   }
   else {
      delta = delta * zoomFactor;
      delta1 = delta1 * zoomFactor;
   }
   axis.setLowerBound(mousX - delta);
   axis.setUpperBound(mousX + delta1);
}
if (zoomY.isSelected()) {

...
}

   event.consume();
}
```

... по игрику аналогично ...

в приведенных выше ссылках тот же принцы просто реализован по другому(с ректанглом неплохо смотрится)... основная проблема в том что если на графике больше 10 000 - 15 000 точек начинаются лаги при масштабировании...

я задавал по етому поводу вопрос но пока безрезультатно... [JavaFX LineChart как ускорить рендеринг при масштабировании графика?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770122/javafx-linechart-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)