# JavaFX LineChart как ускорить рендеринг при масштабировании графика?

Tags: java, javafx, графы, график

написал приложение которое рисует график по данным из файла... добавил функцию зума ... все работает прекрасно вот только когда количество точек на графиках (обычно по три графика) превышает 20 000 - 30 000 точек зум происходит с весьма значительными фризами... а необходимо отрисовать 300 000(5 кГц на 60 секунд записи) точек.... анимацию отключил ... от рисовку точек тоже ... как еще можно ускорить етот процесс ??

или JavaFX не лучшее решение для таких задач???

или я как-то неправильно делаю зум ...
вот часть кода из обработчика ивента на скрол(остальное тоже самое но для Y)

```
public void lineChartOnScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
    NumberAxis axis;
    // scroll amount
    double translateX = (event.getDeltaX())/40;
    double translateY = event.getDeltaY()/40;


    double mousX = lineChart.getXAxis().getValueForDisplay(event.getX() - lineChart.getXAxis().getLayoutX()).doubleValue();
    double mousY = lineChart.getYAxis().getValueForDisplay(event.getY() - lineChart.getYAxis().getLayoutY()).doubleValue();

if (zoomX.isSelected()) {
   axis = (NumberAxis) lineChart.getXAxis();
   axis.setAutoRanging(false);
   double delta  = (mousX - axis.getLowerBound());
   double delta1 = (axis.getUpperBound() - mousX);
   double zoomFactor = 2;

   if (translateY > 0) {
      delta = delta / zoomFactor;
      delta1 = delta1 / zoomFactor;
   }
   else {
      delta = delta * zoomFactor;
      delta1 = delta1 * zoomFactor;
   }
   axis.setLowerBound(mousX - delta);
   axis.setUpperBound(mousX + delta1);
}
if (zoomY.isSelected()) {

...
}

   event.consume();
}
```

Comment: может есть какиенибуть способы типа отключения АнтиАлайсинг фильтра или чего то подобного ... или вынести какиенибуть действия в дельный поток ???